# program a task with node.js... cron or setInterval?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron, setinterval

Maybe it seems an odd question... but I don´t know exactly how to program a task... o rather, I don´t know exactly wich one is the best solution. I just finish a web app and it needs everyweeks, every monday, execute a "special" piece of code, that it can´t be invoked from anywhere else.

The cron solution looks much better, but the piece of code would be isolated, like if this code and the rest of the application were two diferents programs. And the worst handicap of the cron solution (even tough I suposse it can be solved), when I call the javascript file from the cli *node cron.js* it makes good its job, but it never ends... this is normal?? or it depends about the code?? Becouse I don´t want to execute one instance, and the next week, with the first instance still running, run the second, and everyweeks the same problem.

The "setInteval" solution could be setting the time for a day, and testing if it is monday (on monday makes the action)... or maybe setting the time for a week (604800000 miliseconds)... This solution hasn´t these problems, especially the last, but it consumes a lot of resources (I think...no?).

What is the best solution?? Any different?? And if the cron is the best... how to stop the task? (uuuuuhhhh maybe other programed task with cron -a shell- one minute after to kill the node task... uuummm a little botched job).

Thank you very much.

Comment: use cron. in the cron script if I am not wrong, you are thinking that you need to determine the date and fire off execution. that will not be correct. the cron job will do one thing only, it will do the actual job that you need. The input to the cron script can be a csv/json/database. each time it execute it is best to take one row of data as input so all the execution stay in one context.

Comment: Hello @wayne thanks for answer. What I say is that when I execute the script (a node script) with cron, it runs forever... it makes its job and at the end doesn´t close, it continues alive making nothing. And the botched job solution is program other cron task one or two minutes after the first to kill this (something as -pseudocode- $pid = ps -e | grep node; kill $pid;).